# 'of' with 'publishReplay' does not emit value

Tags: rxjs

Example:

```
const data$ = of(777).pipe(
   publishReplay(1)
);

data$.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Expected printing "777" to console. Actual: console is empty:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `data$.connect();` after your subscription.

Alternatively you can use the `refCount` operator after `publishReplay` to do this for you automatically.

Comment: So publishReplay is one of "Connectable Observable Operators". Should check it's docs. Thanks!